# Правильно ли согласованы подлежащее и сказуемое

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, где ошибка в вопросе и как ее исправить?

> Какой человек, или люди, которых вы встретили, приехав в наш
>   регион, оставили у вас сильное впечатление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правилу, если одно из однородных подлежащих имеет форму мн.ч., сказуемое приобретает форму мн.ч. 
**Ср.: Стихи или рассказ печатаются почти в каждом номере этого журнала (Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. Д.Э. Розенталь).**

В вашем же случае лучше написать так: **Какой человек или какие люди, которых вы встретили, приехав в наш регион, оставили у вас сильное впечатление?**

Comment: Запятая перед ИЛИ?

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы мне помогли очень

Comment: я думаю, что запятая не нужна. Так7

Comment: @Jasmin, запятая, конечно, не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо огромное